# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory | reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I do not have a hard project, I only start it. But when I use `npm run dev` node js eat more than 4GB of memory and after it, I see the fatal error:

```
--- Last few GCs --->

[16804:0000018EB02350F0]   128835 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4092.4 (4101.2) -> 4091.5 (4102.4) MB, 2886.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.106, current mu = 0.002) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[16804:0000018EB02350F0]   133745 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4092.7 (4104.7) -> 4091.8 (4104.9) MB, 4899.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.042, current mu = 0.002) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7D7A94BDF napi_wrap+111007
 2: 00007FF7D7A38166 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+59910
 3: 00007FF7D7A39066 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF7D831217E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7D82F6F4D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF7D81A008C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF7D81AB4AA v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
 8: 00007FF7D81A85E9 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
 9: 00007FF7D819D181 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2049
10: 00007FF7D819B385 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1349
11: 00007FF7D81BB7FB v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+203
12: 00007FF7D7EEA2D1 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1409
13: 00007FF7D839B03D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+465325
14: 0000019D8C81DCE3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! top-app@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the top-app@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I use the pretty default package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "debug": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect && next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "stylelint": "stylelint \"**/*.css\" --fix"
},
```

If you need sth else I would add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give node more memory.

A quick workaround can be manually increasing [max_old_space_size](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_old_space_size_size_in_megabytes) in your console. From that moment, all builds will go fine. You can launch this command:

```
SET NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8048
```

If you want a more stable solution, you should change the definition of your `dev` command with something like:

```
SET NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8048 && next dev
```

So that you make sure the `max_old_space_size` is always set to a higher number than default without doing anything different than before.

`8048` is the size in bytes, so 8GB and you can put whatever number you want. If you put more than your RAM, it will go with pagination so it can be a bit slower.

Seamless :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It was just a recursion in components